# IIS with special file names?

Tags: html, iis, handler

I downloaded some websites with "wayback_machine_downloader". Some files had names like `super.html!q=4343`. But IIS is not detecting it as an HTML file and Windows detects the file extension is `.html!q=4343`.

I want thing like this: when people go to `http://www.example.com/super.html!q=4343` I want to show this file as a normal HTML. This in code is just a pure HTML.

I know to change extensions but other HTML files are linking to this `/super.html!q=4343`.

There are also files with different numbers and things. (like `/super.html!q=6556` or `/super.html!d=5545`)

I am not good at writing an English question, but this is my best. Sorry for that.

Is there a way to fix? Thanks!

Comment: You have to implement your own IIS extension for that.

Answer (score 0):

In general you'll need to add a mime map in your website's web.config. For example, to make the URL `http://www.example.com/super.html!q=4343` to work you can do the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension=".html!q=4343" mimeType="text/html" />
      </staticContent>  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The above will only work for the specific extension. To work with all extension use the snippet below. This will work with all extensions.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
         <mimeMap fileExtension="*" mimeType="text/html" />
      </staticContent>  
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I tried to put mime map with file extension .html!q=* as text/html but it gave me some error.

Comment: @ArchiveVEGA yes, that won't work. You'll have to use `fileExtension="*"`. This doesn't affect known mime types, so css/js files won't break with this

Comment: Tasos K's method is greatest and easiest. It is useful in my test.I recommend you to use it